# How can work all custom filters in jquery data table

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

how can I use filters on filters like I selected date from and date to column its show data filter wise and I again select user like expert user and I again select engagement profile than show data filters on filter, Actually I try many code but it didn't work perfectly, how can I do data table in jquery

```js
var minDate, maxDate;

// Custom filtering function which will search data in column four between two values
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
  function(settings, data, dataIndex) {
    var min = minDate.val();
    var max = maxDate.val();
    var date = new Date(data[4]);

    if (
      (min === null && max === null) ||
      (min === null && date <= max) ||
      (min <= date && max === null) ||
      (min <= date && date <= max)
    ) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
);

$(document).ready(function() {

  // Create date inputs
  minDate = new DateTime($('#min'), {
    format: 'MMMM Do YYYY'
  });
  maxDate = new DateTime($('#max'), {
    format: 'MMMM Do YYYY'
  });
  $('#example').DataTable({
    "paging": false,
    "ordering": false,
    "info": false
  });
  //let table = $('#mytable').DataTable({sDom: 'lrtip'});

  // DataTables initialisation
  var table = $('#example').DataTable();

  // Refilter the table
  $('#min, #max').on('change', function() {
    table.draw();
  });
  $('#example tbody th').each(function() {
    var title = $(this).text();
    $(this).html('<input type="text" placeholder="Search ' + title + '" />');
  });

  // DataTable
  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    initComplete: function() {
      // Apply the search
      this.api().columns().every(function() {
        var that = this;

        $('input', this.header()).on('keyup change clear', function() {
          if (that.search() !== this.value) {
            that
              .search(this.value)
              .draw();
          }
        });
      });
    }
  });
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#f1").select2();
  $("#f2").select2();
  $("#f3").select2();
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title></title>
  <style>
    .dataTables_filter,
    .dataTables_info {
      display: none;
    }
  </style>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedheader/3.1.9/css/fixedHeader.dataTables.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/datetime/1.1.0/css/dataTables.dateTime.min.css">
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js">
  </script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.25/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js">
  </script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js">
  </script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/datetime/1.1.0/js/dataTables.dateTime.min.js">
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Date From<input placeholder="Select date" id="min" name="min" class="form-control"> Date To<input placeholder="Select date" id="max" name="max" class="form-control"> Select User(s)
          <select id="f2" class="form-control selectpicker">
            <option data-icon="fa-heart">Expert User</option>
            <option data-icon="fa-heart">Expert User</option>
            <option data-icon="fa-heart">Expert User</option>
          </select>
          Select Engagement Profile(s)
          <select id="f1" class="form-control selectpicker">
            <option data-icon="fa-heart">abc</option>
            <option data-icon="fa-heart">def</option>
          </select>

          Select Event(s)
          <select id="f3" class="form-control selectpicker">
            <option data-icon="fa-heart">DataTable. The </option>
            <option data-icon="fa-heart">DataTable. The example</option>
            <option data-icon="fa-heart">DataTable. The example</option>

          </select>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <table id="example" border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Date</th>
          <th>User</th>
          <th>Engagement Profile</th>
          <th>Event</th>
          <th>Description</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>January 18th 2021</td>
          <td>Expert User</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>edit</td>
          <td>DataTable. The example is the same as the DataTables number range filter, but operating on the Start date column rather th</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>01/18/2021</td>
          <td>Expert User</td>
          <td>audit profile</td>
          <td>edit</td>
          <td>DataTable. The example is the same as the DataTables number range filter, but operating on the Start date column rather th</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>01/18/2021</td>
          <td>Expert User</td>
          <td>def</td>
          <td>edit</td>
          <td>DataTable. The example is the same as the DataTables number range filter, but operating on the Start date column rather th</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>10/18/2021</td>
          <td>Expert User</td>
          <td>hhh</td>
          <td>edit</td>
          <td>DataTable. The example is the same as the DataTables number range filter, but operating on the Start date column rather th</td>
        </tr>

      </tbody>
    </table>





  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

you can show image output

[image]

Comment: Start by having only ONE jQuery library installed and remove `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js">
  </script>`

Comment: When i remove data table js than its not show calendar on date from and date to -

Comment: I did not suggest you removed that. `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js">   </script>` should be removed

Comment: i did it but not work..